# How to create Federated data for Time series data?

Tags: time-series, hdf5, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to study  federated machine learning on time series data. The data is collected from multiple clients. How to convert this data into federated data ?

Comment: Welcome Savita! Could the question be extend to include more details about the original data format, the model to be trained, and any other constraints? This will those who answer provide more relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow Federated we generally consider *federated data* as a dataset pivoted on the clients. It sounds like here it might be useful to pivot on clients, but retain the time series ordering of that data.

[jpgard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5843188/jpgard) gives a great answer in 
[How to create federated dataset from a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965488/how-to-create-federated-dataset-from-a-csv-file) that can be used as an example for other file formats.

Comment: Thank You Zachart Grattet. I have already gone through jpgard. But I have doubt about time series data.