# Build Custom Federated averaging process with ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 3 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

i am trying to load a dataset from csv and perform some federated learning on the available data.

i manage to load a federated dataset from a given csv file and load both the train and the test data.

My question now is how to reproduce a working example to build an iterative process that performs a custom federated averaging on this data.

Here is my code but it's not working:

```
import collections
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff
from absl import app
from tensorflow.keras import layers

from src.main import Parameters

global input_spec


def main(args):
    working_dir = "D:/User/Documents/GitHub/TriaBaseMLBackup/input/fakehdfs/nms/ystr=2016/ymstr=1/ymdstr=26"
    client_id_colname = 'counter'
    SHUFFLE_BUFFER = 1000
    NUM_EPOCHS = 1

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(working_dir):
        file_list = []

        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.csv'):
                file_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
        df_list = []
        for file in file_list:
            df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter="|", usecols=[1, 2, 6, 7], header=None, na_values=["NIL"],
                             na_filter=True, names=["time", "meas_info", "counter", "value"])
            # df_list.append(df[["value"]])

        if df_list:
            rawdata = pd.concat(df_list)

    client_ids = df.get(client_id_colname)
    train_client_ids = client_ids.sample(frac=0.5).tolist()

    # test_client_ids = [x for x in client_ids if x not in train_client_ids]
    example_dataset = train_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(
    train_data.client_ids[0]
     )
    def create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn(client_id):
        # a function which takes a client_id and returns a
        # tf.data.Dataset for that client
        # target = df.pop('value')
        client_data = df[df['value'] == client_id]
        print(df.head())
        features = ['time', 'meas_info', 'value']
        LABEL_COLUMN = 'counter'
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
            (collections.OrderedDict(df[features].to_dict('list')),
             df[LABEL_COLUMN].to_list())
        )
        global input_spec
        input_spec = dataset.element_spec
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER).batch(1).repeat(NUM_EPOCHS)
        return dataset

    train_data = tff.simulation.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(
        client_ids=train_client_ids,
        create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn
    )

    # split client id into train and test clients
    loss_builder = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
    metrics_builder = lambda: [tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]

    def retrieve_model():
        initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=0)
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(2, input_shape=(1, 2), return_sequences=True),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
            tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.nn.softmax),
        ])

        return model

    print(input_spec)

    def tff_model_fn() -> tff.learning.Model:
        return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
            keras_model=retrieve_model(),
            input_spec=example_dataset.element_spec,
            loss=loss_builder(),
            metrics=metrics_builder())

    iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
        tff_model_fn, Parameters.server_adam_optimizer_fn, Parameters.client_adam_optimizer_fn)
    server_state = iterative_process.initialize()

    for round_num in range(Parameters.FLAGS.total_rounds):
        sampled_clients = np.random.choice(
            train_data.client_ids,
            size=Parameters.FLAGS.train_clients_per_round,
            replace=False)
        sampled_train_data = [
            train_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(client)
            for client in sampled_clients
        ]
        server_state, metrics = iterative_process.next(server_state, sampled_train_data)
        train_metrics = metrics['train']
        print(metrics)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main)


def start():
    app.run(main)
```

Here is the input_spec output

```
(OrderedDict([('time', TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), ('meas_info', TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), ('value', TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))]), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

Here is the error that I got

```
ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'batch_input:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'batch_input_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'batch_input_2:0' shape=() dtype=int64>]
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message:
`ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 3 input tensors.` says, the Keras model is defined with only a single input (the first layer in the list):

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(2, input_shape=(1, 2), return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.nn.softmax),
])
```

Try inspecting `model.input_spec` to see what objects the model is expecting to be fed as input.

```py
>>> [InputSpec(shape=(None, None, 2), ndim=3)]
```

Where as the dataset defines and `OrderedDict` of 3 tensors for input features:

```py
features = ['time', 'meas_info', 'value']
LABEL_COLUMN = 'counter'
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
   (collections.OrderedDict(df[features].to_dict('list')),
   df[LABEL_COLUMN].to_list())
)
```

Try inspecting the value of `dataset.element_spec` to see what objects the dataset will feed the model.

To make them compatible will require either changing the model definition, or the dataset. I'll assume the three features in the dataset are desired, in which case we want to tell Keras we have three features from the `OrderedDict`. We'll need to use the [Functional model API from Keras](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/).

```py
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 5
input_dict =  {f: tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(SEQUENCE_LENGTH, 1), name=f) for f in features}
concatenated_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(input_dict.values())
lstm_output = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(2, input_shape=(1, 2), return_sequences=True)(concatenated_inputs)
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu)(lstm_output)
predictions = tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf.nn.softmax)(logits)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_dict, outputs=predictions
```

Note that for the LSTM layer, I needed to provide and extra `SEQUENCE_LENGTH` variable and dimension. The `shape=(SEQUENCE_LENGTH, 1)` will need to be modified to fit the shape of the features coming out of the dataset.

To test if the model and dataset and compatible quickly (without all the other machinery), ensure that the following doesn't raise an error:

```py
model(next(iter(dataset))[0])
```

Comment: i am gettting this error " ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [None]". Any recommendation on how to fix it?

Comment: This is saying the LSTM layer expects shapes `[X, Y, Z]` (ndim=3), but the input layers are providing shapes `[X]` (ndim=1). The tensors expected by the model are not compatible with the tensors being yielded by the dataset. Maybe try looking into whether the dataset is yielding sequences?

Comment: Can you provide me any fixaround i am stuck on that

Comment: i give bounty. Could you please provide me a more detailed answer on how to solve the above error with a working example because I have been stuck.I think that this answer will help many people who they try to build a custom federated learning approach

Comment: Do i need to reshape tf.keras.layers.Reshape((5,3))(concatenated_inputs) to feed lstm with ndim 3?Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience again.  Could  you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467540/build-custom-federated-learning-valueerror-input-0-of-layer-lstm-is-incompatibl