# Error object 'ClientData' has no attribute 'from_clients_and_fn' while building federated dataset

Tags: csv, tensorflow, federated

I am building a federated dataset from a single csv file. I have followed this earlier question
[How to create federated dataset from a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965488/how-to-create-federated-dataset-from-a-csv-file)
While running tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn:

```
train_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(
    client_ids=train_client_ids,
    create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn
)
test_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn(
        client_ids=test_client_ids,
        create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn
    )
```

I am getting error:
AttributeError: type object 'ClientData' has no attribute 'from_clients_and_fn'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from_clients_and_fn` has been changed in the updated documentation as can be seen here: https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/ClientData

The solution is to change for both `train_data` and `test_data`:

1. `from_clients_and_fn` to `from_clients_and_tf_fn`
2. The parameter `create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn` to `serializable_dataset_fn`

Answer (score 1):

For people using TensorFlow Federated 0.20.0+

Try this:

```
train_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_tf_fn(
        client_ids=train_client_ids,
        serializable_dataset_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn
    )
test_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_tf_fn(
        client_ids=test_client_ids,
        serializable_dataset_fn=create_tf_dataset_for_client_fn
    )
```